# Bower + bootstrap theme - how to include fonts?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, gruntjs, bower

I want to use bootstrap theme [Lumen](https://bootswatch.com/lumen/) in my application. I've installed it's pure js and css via `bower`:

```
/* part of bower.json */
{
  "bootstrap.min.css": "https://bootswatch.com/lumen/bootstrap.min.css",
  "bootstrap.min.js": "https://bootswatch.com/lumen/bootstrap.min.css"
}
```

So, two files are installed in the `bower_components/bootstrap.min.css/index.css` and `bower_components/bootstrap.min.js/index.js`. `font_face` option of the `index.css` require the `../fonts/glyphicon-font-name.woff`. So, all fonts for the bootstrap should be placed in the `bower_components/fonts`!

Of course, I can install `bootstrap` bower package and then run `grunt-copy` exactly after every `bower install`, but this method seems wrong. How can I do this fonts requirement on my `./index.html` right?

Comment: The only way to copy dependencies like images and fonts is `grunt-copy`. You can add a postinstall hook to bower to copy the fonts.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy do you mean that's everybody who install bootstrap via bower copy-paste it's font files? It seems very strange. I think there is should be a clean way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the bower package [bootswatch-dist](https://github.com/dbtek/bootswatch-dist) - distribution packages for bootswatch themes.
For installing version of 3.3.5 lumen add the following dependency to bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
 "bootswatch-dist": "3.3.5-lumen"
}
```

Comment: Cool solution. Thanks!